# sql where ActionID in Case x=0 then id in (1,2,3,4) when x=1 then id in (1,2) when x=2 id in (3,4)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I represent the following condition in a sql where clause?

```
where id in 
  Case x=0 then (1,2,3,4) 
  case x=1 then (1,2) 
  case x=2 then (3,4)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
...
 WHERE (x=0 AND id IN (1,2,3,4))
    OR (x=1 AND id IN (1,2))
    OR (x=2 AND id IN (3,4))
```